# Kohana 3.0 paginator does not paginate

Tags: kohana, pagination

i have a problem with the kohana pagination. i have made a method for paginating elements from the database, (let's say 3 on a page), but, (though the pagination links are there), the pagination is not actually done, meaning i always get listed all the elements of the query.
the code i am using:

1. in a helper:

   ```
    public function come_paginate_users(){
    $count = Model::factory('user')->count_all(); //echo $count; exit();

   $pagination = Pagination::factory(array(
   'total_items'    => $count,
   'items_per_page' => 2,
   'auto_hide'      => TRUE,

    ));

   $results = Model::factory('user')->order_by('user_id','ASC')->limit($pagination-                     >items_per_page)->offset($pagination->offset)->find_all();//->execute();

    $page_links = $pagination->render();
    return $pagination;
        }
   ```

in the controller:

```
                $pagination = @helper_utilities::come_paginate_users();
                $this->view->pagination = $pagination;
```

and in the view:

```
               <? echo 'Classic style: '.$pagination;?>
```

but... the pagination is not working. any idea why? thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, You need to return $page_links (wich is rendered html) and $result instead of $pagination object in your come_paginate_users() method

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `total_items` < `items_per_page` and `auto_hide` hides the pagination? Try to set `auto_hide` to `FALSE`